# No se puede cambiar la versión del módulo web dinámico a 2.5 IDE Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, maven

Hago un nuevo proyecto de tipo *maven*. Al intentar cambiar la versión del renglón "`Dynamic Web Module`" a **2.5** en las propiedades del ***IDE Spring Tool Suite*** me manda un error, A pesar de tener *Java 1.7* agregado:

> Cannot change version of project facet Dynamic Web Module to 2.5

Comment: Que version del STS tienes?

Comment: @jasilva **la 3.8.4**

Answer (score 1):

Si no me equivoco. Pulsas encima del proyecto con el botón derecho, properties,project facets y quitas la opción Dynamic Web  Module.
Luego haces otra vez encima del proyecto botón derecho, maven, update project, seleccionas el proyecto que quieres actualizar ( claramente el que estás trabajando con él, aunque normalmente ya te lo selecciona sólo) y le das a Force Update  of Snapshots/Releases y te lo debería de actualizar sin problema

Comment: Otra opción si esa no te funciona, es ir a la carpeta del proyecto, luego .settings buscar el archivo org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core y editar (con el notepad, bloc de notas... el que prefieras) la línea que pone 
  <installed facet="jst.web" version="2.5"/>  cambiar la versión a la que quieras (y puedas) y luego en el eclipse otra vez botón derecho y lo de actualizar

Comment: Lo hice cómo me indicaste al incicio, solo que el formato de las carpetas se descompuso, solo tuve que agregar dos packages y allí agregar un controller que quedaba fuera, además que fue necesario una carpeta nueva "resources" que no la había generado con el proyecto maven pero es necesaria para la versión 2,5 en Dynamic Web Module  y quedó resuelto.